# centrel DB with offline copy

Tags: database

i am looking for a DB framework the allows the use of a central db
with a local full copy of the DB.
in case of network failure i want the application to continue working.
when the network connection is restored, the local copy synchronize will synchronize with the central DB and the application will continue its work with the central DB again.
this way the user will not be hindered by the lack of network.

i have asked around and tried to look for something like this online with out any luck.

has any one encountered any thing that allows this?
i will be very grate full for any direction given.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming that you are in the Microsoft world) do a search for "Microsoft Sync framework".

Comment: thanks. i will look in to it. but i was aiming more towards an open source framework.